# Python chained exceptions: how to access local variables in "root" exception?

Tags: python, exception

I have some utility code to dump the local variables for each frame during Python exception handling. In simplified form, it looks like this:

```
import sys
import traceback

type_, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
for frame, lineno in traceback.walk_tb(tb):
    print(frame.f_locals)
```

This works fine when I have an unchained exception, i.e. something like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 115, in get_context_data
    ...code...
  ...multiple levels of stack trace...
  TypeError: ...
```

prints a set of local variables printed out for each level in the traceback. However, when exception chaining is in effect, i.e.:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 115, in get_context_data
    ...code...
  ...multiple levels of stack trace...
  TypeError: some msg

  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "x.py", ...
     ...
  File  "y.py", ...
     ...
  RuntimeError: some other msg
```

Now, to cope with the chained exception, the code has to loop:

```
    type_, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
    while value:
        for frame, lineno in traceback.walk_tb(tb):
            print(frame.f_locals)
        #
        # Loop for chained exceptions.
        #
        value = value.__cause__ or value.__context__
        _type = value.__class__ if value else None
        tb = value.__traceback__ if value else None
```

The first time around the loop (i.e. the top most code in a.py) correctly prints the frame local variable. But as we follow `value.__cause__` down to the lower frames (x.py and y.py), `frame.f_locals` always seems to be empty. Is there some way to access those variables?

Comment: I should say that I have read several of the related PEPs, notably https://peps.python.org/pep-3134/, which talk about issues to do with GC, but have not been able to determine if that is related to this.